# Devise before_action :authenticate_user! not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I am using devise and what to add the authenticate_user! in the following controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update(user_params)
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to edit_user_registration_path, notice: 'Your account has been updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email)
  end
end
```

The routes are:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "authentications", 
                                  registrations: 'registrations' }
```

I have the following test to verify if the authentication is working:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe RegistrationsController do
  context 'Without being a signed in user' do
    describe 'PATCH #update' do
      let! (:user) { create(:user) }

      it 'gets the correct flash message' do
        patch :update, user: attributes_for(:user)
        flash[:alert].should eql('You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.')
      end

      it 'redirects to the sign in page' do
        patch :update, user: attributes_for(:user)
        response.should redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have the follower user factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name 'John'
    last_name 'Smith'
    sequence(:email) { |n| "John#{n}@example.com" }
    password 'pw'
  end
end
```

I get the following errors when I run the specs:

```
Failures:

  1) RegistrationsController Without being a signed in user PATCH #update redirects to the sign in page
     Failure/Error: patch :update, user: attributes_for(:user)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/controllers/registrations_controller_spec.rb:14:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) RegistrationsController Without being a signed in user PATCH #update gets the correct flash message
     Failure/Error: patch :update, user: attributes_for(:user)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/controllers/registrations_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The before_action :authenticate_user! works correctly in other parts of he application.

Comment: Please show your `factory` for user.

Comment: I added the user factory. Thanks.

Comment: hmm, looks strange, can you add `puts attributes_for(:user)` before `patch :update, user: attributes_for(:user)`?

Comment: `{:first_name=>"John", :last_name=>"Smith", :email=>"John2@example.com", :password=>"pw"}`

Comment: not sure if that can be a problem, but in devise default validation `password` should be 8 characters if you not change it.

Comment: I updated the devise intializer to allow 2 digit passwords while in dev, `config.password_length = 2..128`

Comment: I would run RSpec with -b option to see the full backtrace. Do you have any references to `:name` or `name` in your `User` model?

Comment: sorry but i can't help you to solve this problem, one way it is use `pry` and debug test assertions.

Comment: no references to name in the user model, but multitenant app and name is in the account table, ran the -b but newer so not sure where to look for clues in the backtrace, will did to learn how to use

Answer (score 1):

It appears the tests were failing because I failed to let Devise know which mapping to use which I'm assuming meant it was testing an update method for a different controller.

[Per the Devise docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers): "If you are testing Devise internal controllers or a controller that inherits from Devise's, you need to tell Devise which mapping should be used before a request. This is necessary because Devise gets this information from the router, but since functional tests do not pass through the router, it needs to be told explicitly."

I needed to add `@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]` to the spec.

The following spec worked:

```
  context 'Without being a signed in user' do
    describe 'PATCH #update' do 
      it 'gets the correct flash message' do
        @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
        patch :update, user: { first_name: 'Steve', last_name: "Smith" }
        flash[:alert].should eql('You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.')
      end

      it 'redirects to the sign in page' do
        @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
        patch :update, user: { first_name: 'Steve', last_name: "Smith" }
        response.should redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
      end
    end
  end
```